# How to get CLOB into XML as an atribute

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to get sql_fulltext from v$sqlarea into xml as one of the xmlattributes, but it throws ora-00932 at me. So, is there any way to get CLOB into XML as atribute (even better if that CLOB can be encoded as base64, for case that contains some XML code)?

Comment: How are you currently trying to do it - what is the query that gives you the ORA-00932 error?

Comment: the query is like this (just vith more atributes):`SELECT xmlagg(xmlelement ("S", xmlattributes(s.sql_fulltext AS "FT"))) xml_ret
  FROM
  (SELECT sql_fulltext FROM v$sqlarea) s;`

Comment: OK, using that you can get the first 4000 characters of each statement; do you have any longer than that? And if so does it matter if they are truncated?

Comment: unfortunately I need full sql_fulltext and i think it can be, in some rare cases, longer than 4000 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get up to 4000 characters of the SQL text using `dbms_lob.substr()`:

```
SELECT xmlagg(xmlelement ("S",
  xmlattributes(dbms_lob.substr(s.sql_fulltext, 4000, 1) AS "FT"))) xml_ret
FROM v$sqlarea s;
```

The attribute value [is escaped by default](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#CHDBDAGE), so a less-than sign will be shown as `&lt;` for example.

If you need more than 4000 characters (or bytes) of the SQL text then you could use [the `dbms_xmlgen` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB5047).

You could also extract the data as an XML element (which allows CLOBs), and then use an XQuery to transform the element to an attribute via an XPath constructor:

```
select x.xml_ret
from (
  select xmlelement("S", xmlelement("FT", sql_fulltext)) as x
  from v$sqlarea
) s
cross join xmltable('for $i in /S
  return element S{attribute FT {$i/FT/text()} }'
  passing s.x
  columns xml_ret xmltype path '.'
) x;
```

You can add in other attributes or elements in the inline view and extract them with additional `columns` clauses.